# ITelephony.aidl in Android Studio / gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, aidl

Where do I add aidl files when using Android Studio / gradle? The file structure is a bit different than from eclipse:

[image]

I have tried to add `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` at all three levels, but it doesn't seem to compile:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer myself. For others interested, here it is:

[image]